# SQL - Multiplying columns

Tags: sql, oracle, maximo

I cannot get this to work

```
SELECT PM.PMNUM, (COUNT(ROUTE_STOP.LOCATION) * JOBPLAN.JPDURATION) 
FROM PM
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROUTE_STOP ON ROUTE_STOP.ROUTE = PM.ROUTE
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOBPLAN ON JOBPLAN.JPNUM = PM.JPNUM
GROUP BY PM.PMNUM
```

Comment: 1) Are you *sure* you want to use outer joins on this? 2) What happens when you execute this query? Is there an error, or are the results not what you expected, or do choirs of angels sing "Hallelujah", or what? 3) Please edit your question and provide sample table contents, expected output, and the output you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: Providing sample data and desired results *as well as* explaining the error would make your question more understandable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I see your minimum missing a group by.

```
SELECT PM.PMNUM, (COUNT(ROUTE_STOP.LOCATION) * JOBPLAN.JPDURATION) 
FROM PM
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROUTE_STOP ON ROUTE_STOP.ROUTE = PM.ROUTE
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOBPLAN ON JOBPLAN.JPNUM = PM.JPNUM
GROUP BY PM.PMNUM, JOBPLAN.JPDURATION
```

If this won't help you need to give further feedback what is not working?

Comment: If I post again i will make sure i include  sample table contents, expected output, and the output you're getting.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this would be great. :-)